# History of summing integers with natural powers

Tags: discoveries, mathematicians, ancient-india

In my 10th class school material, it is given that **Aryabhatta**  discovered the following formulas:

$\sum n=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$

$\sum n^2=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

$\sum n^3=\dfrac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$

Is he the first person to discover these formula? If this is true, then who discovered the formula for the generalization $\sum n^k$ ?

Comment: Would the formula for $\sum n^k$ be [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)?

Comment: +1) Very good teacher. Still learning ... as everyone should be, but teachers especially.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.**

In [The bridge between the continuous and the discrete via original sources in *Study the Masters: The Abel-Fauvel Conference*](http://www.math.nmsu.edu/~davidp/bridge.pdf), Pengelley writes that

- In the 6th century B.C., the Pythagoreans knew about the formula for $\sum n$.
- In the 3rd century B.C., Archimedes figured out the formula for $\sum n^2$.
- In the 1st century A.D., Nichomachus figured out the formula for $\sum n^3$.